# How to set timeout on prompting user for yes or no to shutdown Windows PC?

Tags: batch-file, shutdown

I am trying to shutdown Windows at specific time every day.

I am using task scheduler to shutdown Windows at a specific time. I am using a batch a file for this which is working.

```
set /p a="Are you turn off computer (y/n)"
if %a%==y (shutdown.exe /s /t 00) else (echo "")
```

I want to add some other functions in that. I already added user input and if else statement which ask from user to shutdown Windows or not.

Now I want to add a command which checks and executes shutdown command if user does not give any input within a certain time, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command:

```
choice /t 10 /d y /m "Shutdown"
if errorlevel 2 (echo that's a no & goto :eof)
shutdown /s /t 0
```

`/t 10` gives a timeout of 10 seconds.
`/d y` is the default (what's chosen after the timeout)
`/m "Shutdown` is the prompt string.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "a="
set /p a="Are you turn off computer (y/n)"
if not defined a echo no user entry
if "%a%"=="y" (shutdown.exe /s /t 00) else (echo "")
```

The issue with `set /p` is that if the user makes no entry, then the variablename that is being `set` remains unchanged. Consequently, it should be set to *nothing* initially.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

The `IF` statement can also accept the `/i` switch (after the `NOT` - if used) to make the string-comparison case-insensitive.